# jQuery multiple filter (checkboxes and dropdown) data attributes

Tags: jquery

need little help here. I am working on data attribute filter on my project that require filtering with 1 dropdown and 4 checkboxes (maybe more). I'm done with simple filter with 1 dropdown and 2 checkboxes following this code below

```
$('#filterDiv').on("change keyup", function() {
  chkBox = { datatest: null };

  if ($('.3').is(':checked') && $('.4').is(':checked')) {
     chkBox.datatest = "";
  } else if ($('.3').is(':checked')) {
     chkBox.datatest = "1";
  } else if ($('.4').is(':checked')) {
     chkBox.datatest = "6";
  } else {
     chkBox.datatest = "";
  }

  $("p").hide().filter(function() {
    var rtnData = "";

    regExA          = new RegExp($('#1').val().trim(), "ig");
    regExTest       = new RegExp(chkBox.datatest, "ig");

        rtnData = (
      $(this).attr("data-name").match(regExA) && 
      $(this).attr("data-test").match(regExTest) 
    );

    //console.log(rtnData);
    return rtnData;
  }).show();
});
```

here are fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/legazy7891/t9krfjpy/7/

As seen above the logic is only for 2 checkboxes, and i don't want to create condition (if else) for every checkboxes.

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks